# Is it considered good practice to unset PHP variables in this scenario?

Tags: php, coding-style

Right now, I am using a modified version of OsCommerce that has a lot of variables declared in its `application_top.php` file (which is included when going to every file on the website as the first thing).

So for instance, if I go to `mypage.php`, `application_top.php` is included in the top.

I only want some of the variables defined from my `application_top.php` file to be accessible inside the `mypage.php` file, since they are used for temporary calculations or whatever, whereas others are meant to be accessible from the page.

What would be the best practise? To unset variables that are meant to be used in the local scope after use, and to leave all variables that are meant to be accessed alone?

Comment: the best practice is not to use scripts which do not use classes and namespaces

Comment: Read my comment on @user1281385's answer.

Answer (score 0):

use of classes would be the best way, and just passing the variables you need

Though I assume this will be a major rewrite ?

What about something like this

```
$vars = array_keys(get_defined_vars());
$whitelist = array("var1", "var2" ...);
$vars = array_diff(array_keys($whitelist), $vars);
foreach($vars as $var) {
    unset($$var); 
}
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately refactoring hasn't been of key importance for the past 10 years within the company. I am slowly introducing them to the concept and its importance, as well as Test Driven Development. We're taking a few steps at a time.